# Progressive web app - displaying websites

Tags: iframe, progressive-web-apps

I've got a question regarding PWAs. I'm supposed to create one, which should be displaying random webpages and a user should be able to answer some questions about them.
With ordinary web apps I've got a problem with iframes - sometimes it displays an incomplete page (for example without ads) or it doesn't appear at all.

Is there any way to resolve this issue while using PWAs?

Comment: A PWA is just a regular website with some extra functionality added. So if you build it the same way, you will probably have the same issues. Perhaps you should post a questions/issue with your current problem and what you have tried to fix that.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.